# Are my assumptions about configuration correct?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, rest, cxf

I want to use to implement only REST service - a very simple one returning 'person' by full name or id in JSON. Im probably will be using JAX-RS and maybe JAXB - im not sure if tis is a right choise. I want to use it with following technologies/products and their versions:

1. JDK 1.5
2. Eclipse 3.5 EE
3. Tomcat 6.0
4. CXF 2.2.5
5. Spring 2.5.1

My questions are:

1. Can i use JDK 1.5 and tomcat 6 together?
2. Can i use Spring 2.5.1 and JDK 1.6 together (if i want to upgrade)?
3. Does CXF 2.2.5 and Spring 2.5.1 will be working without any problems?

Im asking, because i have:

- JDK 1.6
- eclipse 3.5 ee
- tomcat 6
- cxf 2.2.5
- spring 2.5.1

and i cant get them working with even simpliest REST WS, for example:

[Developing RESTful Web Services using Apache CXF and Maven2](http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.com/2009/04/developing-restful-web-services-using.html)

But I have to say: **for now I do not want to use Maven.**

Comment: How could we help if you don't provide details on what's not working? *"I cant get them working with even simpliest REST WS"* is not enough, even with Jedi skills.

Comment: Early releases of Spring 2.5.x were a bit wobbly. Strongly advise you upgrade to 2.5.6, which is rock solid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short :

1. yes
2. yes
3. havent used it, but should be OK

Note : you are talking about JSON and about CXF / JAXB. Both CXF and JAXB are XML oriented more than JSON oriented. I dont even know if they can be used to generate JSON. If you want a simple JSON service, CXF and JAXB are probably overkill ...

Comment: Honestly im newbie at web java :). I should incluce lib files for jaxb, cxf, httpclient and so on in lib directory, that was solution for my problem. Tnx for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Does CXF 2.2.5 and Spring 2.5.1 will be working without any problems?** -- I can't say as I never used that combo. But as @Skaffman said there's no reason to be using **2.5.1** you should really be on **2.5.6** which works with both Java 5,6 and Tomcat 6. As for using JAXB for your JSON rpresentations I would look at this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071749/how-to-reuse-jerseys-json-jaxb-for-serialization).