# Jersey JSON marshalling of empty lists

Tags: java, json, list, jaxb, jersey

We have a Java List of objects which is marshalled via JSON which is created by Jersey.

The List is called "rows".  When there is data we have:

```
{"records":"1","page":"1","total":"1","rows":[{"id":"692334","cell":["ECS","D","201009","","0","ABCD","11","11","","201009"]}]}
```

When there is no data we have:

```
{"page":0,"records":0,"total":0}
```

How can we make Jersey include the `rows` field even if the List has a size of 0?  What we want is:

```
{"page":0,"records":0,"total":0,"rows":[]}
```

Note that we are already using a JAXB ContextResolver to [ensure](http://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/configuring_json_for_restful_web) the JSON is correct for a single row.  Not sure if we can configure this resolver to solve our problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Jackson JAX-RS provider instead of alternatives (badgerfish/jettison), which does not do XML-to-JSON conversion. Missing array is most likely due to this conversion. There are multiple ways to configure this (jersey mailing list should have a few), and latest versions may expose it directly via Jersey API.

Comment: Never got around to trying this but it does seem like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e903

seems that some array problems can be solved by using something like this:

```
JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("yourArrayName").build()
```

At least it solves the issue, when the list contains only 1 item it's also formated as an JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve JSON array "bug" in Jersey json library. Secret ingredient is previusly mentioned JSONConfiguration and ContextResolver magic. See my following post it has a full code example, customized ContextResolver and rest Application class might be somewhat fuzzy logic in first look.

[How to serialize Java primitives using Jersey REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629544/how-to-serialize-java-primitives-using-jersey-rest/12624152#12624152)

- json array for zero or single-element Java lists
- primitive integer or boolean fields without quotation chars