# Issue with serializing single-element ArrayList to JSON

Tags: java, json

I am writing Junit test case for my REST service, i am setting the values(below is the piece of code) to get the payload required for REST service

```
Payload jsonPayload = new Payload ();
payload.setAcc("A");
List<Details> details= new ArrayList<Details>;
Details detail = new Details();
detail.setTotalAmount(1);
detail.setCurrency("dollar");
details.add(detail);
payload.getDetails().addAll(details);
```

I want JSON to be built in format mentioned below, but I am not getting the JSON as expected, details should be in form of Array.

**Required JSON -**

```
   {
  "Acc" : "A",
    "details": [
     { 
      "totalAmount":1,
      "currency":"dollar"
     }
   ]
 }
```

**Output JSON -**

```
 {
 "Acc" : "A",
  "details": 
   { 
     "totalAmount":1,
     "currency":"dollar"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: See discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214827/how-to-make-jersey-jackson-serialize-empty-list-single-element-list-as-an-array

Comment: What happens when you add 2 or more details?

Comment: Btw, your question summary is misleading. It should point to json format problem

Comment: You should also specify which json library you are using

Comment: @Yugo - I am getting proper array in the required format if i pass more than 1 details

Comment: @semperfids, I am not using any JSON library. I am writing junit test case for REST service and using setters and getters to build JSON data, as REST is not getting the data in required format, it's throwing any error

Comment: Perhaps the link posted by @Robert would help you though

Comment: I tried using JAXBContextResolver, but the request is not going to JAXBContextResolver code

Comment: JAXBContextResolver is working only for GET methods, not for POST