# Reading Element attribute value using XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am not able lookup attribute value of an element. My XML is

```
<Person>
          <BirthDate>2008-01-04</BirthDate>
          <FirstName>Affo</FirstName>
          <Gender tc="200">Male</Gender>
          <LastName></LastName>
          <Occupation>false</Occupation>
          <Age>4</Age>
</Person>
```

I am interested in `<Gender tc="200">Male</Gender>`. My POJO looks like this:

```
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String Occupation;
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("tc")
    private String genderTC;
    private String Gender;
    private String birthDate;
    private int age;
```

From XML is

```
            XStream stream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
        stream.processAnnotations(PersonType.class);
        PersonType person = (PersonType) stream.fromXML(file);

        System.out.println(person.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(person.getGenderTC());
        System.out.println(person.getGender());
```

Here for `person.getGenderTC()` I am getting null. Interesting part is when I reversed the process and generated the xml using same PersonType pojo, I got following XML:

```
<Person tc="111">
  <FirstName>Himanshu</FirstName>
  <Gender>M</Gender>
  <Age>28</Age>
</Person>
```

Comment: Check out the section "Mapping Objects to Simple Content":  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan But here again I have to create a separate class to get internal attributes. Right?

Comment: Yes, if you are interested in using EclipseLink MOXy I can show you how it can be down without introducing a separate class.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I have analyzed EclipseLinkMOXy earlier and didn't like it's implementation. As it needs a property file to be added in the model class folder.

Comment: The `jaxb.properties` file is required when using MOXy with the standard JAXB (JSR-222) APIs.  You can of course use the native APIs.  I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan That's great and I appreciate your support. Can you please tell me how can I integrate EclipseLink MOXy with my project without using jaxb.properties? What are the libraries/JARs to include? In between I am aware of EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation to get attribute. My only hunch is jaxb.properties file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @BlaiseDoughan That's great and I appreciate your support. Can you
>   please tell me how can I integrate EclipseLink MOXy with my project
>   without using jaxb.properties? What are the libraries/JARs to include?
>   In between I am aware of EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation to get
>   attribute. My only hunch is jaxb.properties file.

**Person**

Below is how you could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` annotation to do the mapping you are looking for:

```
package forum11417620;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(name="FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name="LastName")
    private String lastName;

    @XmlElement(name="Occupation")
    private String occupation;

    @XmlPath("Gender/@tc")
    private String genderTC;

    @XmlPath("Gender/text()")
    private String gender;

    @XmlElement(name="BirthDate")
    private String birthDate;

    @XmlElement(name="Age")
    private int age;

}
```

**Demo**

Below is an example of how you can bootstrap a MOXy `JAXBContext` without a `jaxb.properties` file.

```
package forum11417620;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {Person.class}, null);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11417620/input.xml");
        Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person>
   <FirstName>Affo</FirstName>
   <LastName></LastName>
   <Occupation>false</Occupation>
   <Gender tc="200">Male</Gender>
   <BirthDate>2008-01-04</BirthDate>
   <Age>4</Age>
</Person>
```

**Required Binaries** (from http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/)

***Option #1 - EclipseLink JAR (from Installer Zip)***

- eclipselink.jar

***Option #2 - MOXy bundles (from OSGi Bundles Zip)***

- org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar

***Maven***

I have example `pom.xml` files on Git Hub as part of some examples from my blog:

- https://github.com/bdoughan

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am able to run it perfectly. I find that Eclipse Link supports JPA too. Ultimately I have save this POJO into DB using Hibernate. Can you please refer tutorial for the same?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav - I have the following JPA related tutorials:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/JPA.  I would recommend using the standard JPA APIs as this will allow you to swap JPA providers at a later date if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

As you have it, this code:

```
@XStreamAsAttribute 
@XStreamAlias("tc") 
private String genderTC;
```

is expecting the attribute `tc` to be on the enclosing `Person` node of the XML.

I think you need to define a second pojo type to deserialize the Gender data, including the genderTC attribute as well as the Gender element.

Comment: Is it? I have thousands of elements with just one attribute. Is there any other way to do it, using Converter or XPath of something.

Comment: ToAttributedValueConverter is a possible solution, per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460810/how-to-read-list-elements-with-attribute-via-xstream (though it does require a child POJO per Chris' comment). You can make the child POJO an inner class of your Person class though to minimise the impact.