# How do I get Json generated by MOXy to understand when model are numbers

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

To solve another problem I have moved from using [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) to [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) to generate JSON from a JAXB created object model ( created by Sun JAXB 2.1.12). One difference I've noticed is that in the object model numeric attribute are defined as

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "nonNegativeInteger")
protected BigInteger count;
```

Jersey converts to

```
"count":1,
```

but MOXy gives

```
"count" : "1",
```

How can I get MOXy to realize its a numeric field and not quote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

A fix has been checked into the EclipseLink 2.4.1 and 2.5.0 streams.  You can download a nightly label containing this fix starting **July 13, 2012** from the following link:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) will marshal numeric types to JSON without quotes.  In this case the presence of `@XmlSchemaType` annotation is causing a problem.  This is a bug and you can use the following link to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/384919

**WORKAROUND**

MOXy's external mapping document can be used to override mappings at the field/property level.  We will leverage this to remap the `count` property to remove the problematic `@XmlSchemaType` annotation.

**oxm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum11448966">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Root">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="count"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Root**

```
package forum11448966;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "nonNegativeInteger")
    protected BigInteger count;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum11448966;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(3);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum11448966/oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Root.class}, properties);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.count = BigInteger.TEN;

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
{
   "count" : 10
}
```

Comment: Hi, ok that works but I dont really see how simply adding <xml-element java-attribute="count"/> fixes this, although it does. It is going to be a bit of pain adding these for each integral value so I wondered if I could drop @XmlSchemaType(name = "nonNegativeInteger") instead, although I dont know if SUNJAXB needs it to generate valid xml, and or/whether I can stop SUNJAXB adding the annotation when it creates the model in the first place ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor - I've updated my answer to explain why the workaround works.  We are currently working on the fix.  Sun JAXB doesn't require that annotation to produce valid XML, it only affects how an XML schema is generated.

Comment: Updated, great there is a fix do you know when that will find its way into a maven snaphot ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor - It will be in the maven snapshot tomorrow.