# How an I get MOXy to just output on one line to save space

Tags: java, json, jersey, eclipselink, moxy

To solve another problem I have moved from using Jersey to EclipseLink MOXy to generate JSON from a JAXB created object model ( created by Sun JAXB 2.1.12). One difference I've noticed is the formatting of the output

that Jersey outputs

```
{"artist-list":{"offset":0,"count":1,"artist":[{"score":"100","type":"Group","id":"4302e264-1cf0-4d1f-aca7-2a6f89e34b36","name":"Farming Incident","sort-name":"Incident, Farming","gender":"male","country":"AF","disambiguation":"the real one","ipi-list":{"ipi":["1001","1002"]},"life-span":{"begin":"1999-04","ended":"true"},"tag-list":{"tag":[{"count":5,"name":"thrash"},{"count":11,"name":"güth"}]}}]}}
```

but MOXy gives

```
"count" : "1",
   "offset" : "0",
   "artist" : [ {
      "id" : "4302e264-1cf0-4d1f-aca7-2a6f89e34b36",
      "type" : "Group",
      "score" : "100",
      "name" : "Farming Incident",
      "sort-name" : "Incident, Farming",
      "gender" : "male",
      "country" : "AF",
      "disambiguation" : "the real one",
      "ipis" : [ "1001", "1002" ],
      "life-span" : {
         "begin" : "1999-04",
         "ended" : "true"
      },
      "tags" : [ {
         "count" : "5",
         "name" : "thrash"
      }, {
         "count" : "11",
         "name" : "güth"
      } ]
   } ]
}
```

Moxy is much prettier :) 
But one of the reasons to move to make our data available via Json is to reduce transmission bandwidth so is it possible to get MOXy to generate all one line, and without the extra spaces around each : ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) will marshal the JSON to one line.  To get formatted output you need to set the following property on the `Marshaller`:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
```

**Root**

```
package forum11450509;

public class Root {

    private String foo;
    private int bar;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

The following code demonstrates how to specify formatted output:

```
package forum11450509;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Root.class}, properties);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setFoo("ABC");
        root.setBar(123);

        System.out.println("One Line:");
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

        System.out.println("\nFormatted:");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
One Line
{"bar":123,"foo":"ABC"}
Formatted:
{
   "bar" : 123,
   "foo" : "ABC"
}
```

---

**JAX-RS**

The same behaviour holds for `MOXyJsonProvider` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html).

***One Line***

By default when you include `MOXyJsonProvider` in your JAX-RS application, the output will be marshalled on one line:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class CustomerApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(2);
        set.add(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
        set.add(CustomerService.class);
        return set;
    }

}
```

***Formatted Output***

You can also configure `MOXyJsonProvider` to produce formatted output:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class CustomerApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(1);
        set.add(ExampleService.class);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();
        moxyJsonProvider.setFormattedOutput(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah should have seen this I was looking at my initialcontext method rather than my marshaller initialization, disabled Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT and it now works

Comment: @Blaise I have a question. I have specified moxy as the JAXB Provider by giving the entry javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory in jaxb.properties file. I have not specified moxyjsonprovider for json output. In my case, what will be used to provide json output? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @user2186831 - It depends.  There isn't a standard JSON-binding provider for all environments, so you will get the default for the env you are using.  In GlassFish 4 for example the default would be MOXy:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxy-is-new-default-json-binding.html