# REST service: how to produce human readable output using XML + XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a REST service implemented in GlassFish using Jersey. I have the service working using JSON output, now I would like to provide some human readable output as well. The most important thing missing in the JSON output is I want some fields in the statistics to be transformed to a clickable links, which would display a related statistics (using anoother REST call).

As I want to keep formatting and content separate, I do not want to produce HTML directly. I though using xml + xslt might be a sensible approach. I can use org.w3c.dom to produce a XML document, but I see no way how to attach a xslt to it.

Here is approximately what I do now:

```
@GET
@Path("history_id")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Document history(@QueryParam("id") String idText) throws ParserConfigurationException
{
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("root");
        doc.appendChild(root);
        Element el = doc.createElement(name);
        el.setTextContent(value);
        root.appendChild(el);
        return doc;
```

I would like following directive to appear in the XML produced:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="history.xsl"?">
```

How can I specify a xslt to be attached to the XML? Or is my approach perhaps fundamentally wrong and this is usually done in some other way?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to show the XML in a human readable way? Is it for displaying in part of a webpage (for example as part of an API visualizer, ie [Swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com/) type approach) or is it for some other reason?

Comment: @My Head Hurts I want to produce some statistics, which may be consumed by an application (this I currently do using JSON), but they might be sometimes inspected by a human as well, and for this I would like to add some formatting (most important is to implement clickable links on some fields to display related statistics) as a convenience.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts It should be possible to provide a XML webpage with a XSLT stylesheet and web browser should be able to do the transformation and formatting on its side, line in http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simplexsl.xml. I understand I could do the transformation on the server, but somehow that feels like an inferior solution.

Comment: Have you considered using JAXB to produce both XML and JSON from the same domain objects? Have a look at http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11012294/116509

Comment: @artbristol It seems like a reasonable way for many scenarios, but it does not seem to fit my purpose very well. 1) My output does not correspond directly to the database objects, I output some aggregated stats, not the objects themselves. 2) This seems to produce HTML, not XML.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I am trying to implement the solution in the link provided, but I do not see any XSLT attached to the DOM produced by the transformation. I will study it a bit more to understand it. If that works, it might be an answer.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I do not see any xslt being attach in the example. I am not sure I undestand it correctly, but the only output property set is indentation using transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4"); - am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "directive" is called a "processing instruction" in the XML world. You can create one with the DOM API:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    doc.appendChild(doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"history.xsl\""));
```

Then, if you send the XML document to a browser/user agent that supports client-side XSLT it will apply the stylesheet to the XML.