# REST: Can a client pass a wrapper object through POST?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

Is it possible to pass a wrapper object using POST to a REST Web Service?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with _wrapper object_ but the server would have to know about that wrapper object. You can't just create an object and send it to the server since it wouldn't know how to deserialize it.

Comment: I think this question may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071749/how-to-reuse-jerseys-json-jaxb-for-serialization

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can  pass a Wrapper Oject (A object of a class  ).

Examples of jersey Rest client :
Adding dependency :

```
         <!-- jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

ForGetMethod and passing two parameter :

```
          Client client = Client.create();
           WebResource webResource1 = client
                        .resource("http://localhost:10102/NewsTickerServices/AddGroup/"
                                + userN + "/" + groupName);

                ClientResponse response1 = webResource1.get(ClientResponse.class);
                System.out.println("responser is" + response1);
```

GetMethod  passing one parameter and Getting a Respone of List :

```
       Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource1 = client
                    .resource("http://localhost:10102/NewsTickerServices/GetAssignedUser/"+grpName);    
    //value changed
    String response1 = webResource1.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);

    List <String > Assignedlist =new ArrayList<String>();
     JSONArray jsonArr2 =new JSONArray(response1);
    for (int i =0;i<jsonArr2.length();i++){

        Assignedlist.add(jsonArr2.getString(i));    
    }
```

In Above It Returns a List which we are accepting as a List and then converting it to Json Array and then Json Array to List .

If  Post Request passing Json Object as Parameter :

```
   Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client
            .resource("http://localhost:10102/NewsTickerServices/CreateJUser");
    // value added

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class,mapper.writeValueAsString(user));

    if (response.getStatus() == 500) {

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("User already exist "));
    }
```

Here  User is a object of user class . which m pssing in post parameter .