# Return complex collection to client in REST Jersey?

Tags: java, rest

I need to return a collection to calling client from REST webservice,

I did a wrapper something like below,

**

- bean Wrapper

**

```
    public Collection<FundBalanceSetProperties> getVal() {
        return ListN;
    }

    public void setVal(Collection<FundBalanceSetProperties> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.ListN = list;
}
```

I tried to get the value set as below,

**

- REST Service

**

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML })
public Todo getHTML() throws Exception {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    Collection<FundBalanceSetProperties> list = myDal.getFundBalanceSet(null, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    todo.setVal(list);
    return todo;
}
```

But I am getting error

> "Exception in thread "main"
>
> com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException:"

Can someone please help me with returning collection to calling client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two easy options you have are:

1. Return an Array (FundBalanceSetProperties[]) instead of a Collection
2. Use Jackson: [How to reuse Jersey's JSON/JAXB for serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071749/how-to-reuse-jerseys-json-jaxb-for-serialization)

Comment: Upvoting and recommending Jackson as well.